# Ajax post to route in Laravel 4

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I am going to send some data to **current page** using ajax to insert something in database.
Assume this ajax code:

```
$('#newPost :submit').click(function(e){
            var BASE = 'http://localhost/project/public/';
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(BASE, {
        'message' : $('#newPost textarea.message').val()
        }, function(data) {
        $('#content').prepend('<p>' + data + '</p>');
    });
});
```

This piece of code sends data to URL / and it works well. but I want to send it to a **Route.Name** which route sends it to a controller@action.
is there anyway or workaround to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your route,

```
Route::get('data', array('uses' => 'HomeController@store'));
```

In HomeController,

```
public function store() {
  $input = Input::all(); // form data
  // validation rules
  $rules = array(
    'email'   => 'required|email', 
    'name'    => 'required', 
  ); 

  $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules); // validate
  // error handling
  if($validator->fails()) {
    if(Request::ajax()) {   // it's an ajax request                 
      $response = array(
         'response'  =>  'error',
         'errors'    =>  $validator->errors()->toArray()
      );                
    } else { // it's an http request
       return Redirect::intended('data')
                  ->withInput()
                  ->withErrors($validator);
    }
  } else { // validated
     // save data
  }
}
```

And finally the script,

```
var root_url = "<?php echo Request::root(); ?>/"; // put this in php file
$('#newPost :submit').click(function(e){
    var BASE = root_url + 'data';
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(BASE, {
        'message' : $('#newPost textarea.message').val()
        }, function(data) {
        $('#content').prepend('<p>' + data + '</p>');
    });
});
```

Comment: so I need to use Request::ajax() to check whether it's an ajax request or not. in regular use, to send back errors I used `$errors->has`, how can I have access to $errors after ajax submiting?!

Answer (score 2):

You could change

```
var BASE = 'http://localhost/project/public/';
```

to

```
var BASE = '<php echo URL::route("name");?>'
```

Your route should then be:

```
Route::post('action', array('as' => 'name', 'uses' => 'HomeController@action'));
```

Note the use of the [named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) instead of building the url using `URL::to('controller/action')`

Comment: is this Laravel 4 syntax?

Comment: so I need to use Request::ajax() to check whether it's an ajax request or not. in regular use, to send back errors I used $errors->has, how can I have access to $errors after ajax submiting?!

Comment: You could send a different response in case you have errors or not